# conflict between views and pathauto

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

if i create a path alias to a node, say 'press' and i have a view page display on path 'press/archives', why does 'press/archive' leads my users to 'press'?

see related [Fundamental understanding of how Views and Pathauto work together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913736/fundamental-understanding-of-how-views-and-pathauto-work-together)

Answer (score 0):

A way around this is to make a custom view with page URL "press" that only retrieves the one node and shows the full node content, so that the URL token is handled by Views and not by the menu system.

Comment: If the node path is defined in the menu system this will be seen by Drupal before the Views paths are checked.